# Getting the activity tree android

Tags: java, android, testing, android-activity

Hi just wondering is it possible to get an idea about which activity precedes which activity?
From android manifest file we can get a list of activity. But is it possible to get information such as which activity can be reached from which activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get this information statically (by just looking at the manifest file, for example). At runtime, an app can decide to launch any different activity based on decisions made at the time.

You might be able to guess a limited version of "can we go from activity A to activity B" by looking at the code for activity A, but that will not be guaranteed to find everything.